# Rails 2.3.8 tiny mce issue - undefined method `uses_tiny_mce'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinymce

I am facing an issue in my application with tiny mce. 
All the gem version & ruby version is OK on my system, but it is giving me error 
= undefined method `uses_tiny_mce'

Here i installed the tiny_mce gem. COnfigured it correctely, but still there is an issue.

Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not using this as a plugin. 
I have followed the steps given in the,

http://enginey.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/vendor/plugins/tiny_mce/README.rdoc

Steps :

script/plugin install git://github.com/kete/tiny_mce.git
rake tiny_mce:install

my issue got resolved.

Answer (score 2):

Did you include

```
config.gem 'tiny_mce'
```

in *config/environment.rb*?

I have used this gem in the past too, but have stopped using it. I figured it complicated the setup and deployment of my Rails apps. Since then I have just used the TinyMCE editor by itself. Since it is 100% javascript, it does not touch any Ruby code which keeps things better organized.

Comment: Thanks Joost, I have added the line in the environment.rb file. But it doesn't helped me :( I have followed all the instructions from https://github.com/kete/tiny_mce

Comment: I was not using this as a plugin, i have followed the steps given in the http://enginey.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/vendor/plugins/tiny_mce/README.rdoc